# merge row with two column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

i have two table, i want merge that data in one table how it is possible
my data is look like this,

```
     table1 (col1 is column name)                

     col1    
     ------------------               
     data1                    
     data2                 
     data3               
     data4
     data5


     table2 (col1 is column name)

     col1
     -----------------------
     data5
     data6
     data7


     expected Result
     col1 and col2 are my columns


     col1          col2
     --------------------------
     data1         data5
     data2         data6
     data3         data7
     data4
     data5
```

Comment: SQL JOIN would be my first guess...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by adding a `join` key using `row_number()`:

```
select t1.col1, t2.col1 as col2
from (select col1, row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from table1
     ) t1 full outer join
     (select col1, row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from table2
     ) t2
     on t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum;
```

Note:  the ordering for the two columns is not guaranteed to be the same as in your example.  You would need a column to specify the ordering.  If you have only one column, then that wouldn't seem to be the case.  But, this will produce the two columns as in your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT col1, col2 
FROM (
      SELECT col1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1) rn FROM table1
) a
FULL OUTER JOIN (
      SELECT col1 col2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1) rn FROM table2
) b
  ON a.rn = b.rn
ORDER BY COALESCE(a.rn, b.rn);
```

Here - lacking any other sort criteria - I order the columns by their value. If you have some other sort criteria, you'll have to change the `ORDER BY` clause in `OVER()` to reflect that. The join key is generated dynamically using ROW_NUMBER() over the specified ordering.

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2b387/3).

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.col1,t2.col as'col2' from table1 t1,table2 t2
```